# Change color of onscreen button bar

Tags: android, themes, android-manifest

I'm trying to change the color of the on screen button bar:
[image]

I've managed to change the status bar color via the Android Manifest like this:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.WebViewApp.Gray"
```

However I can't seem to figure out how to change from this purple color.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This section of screen called NavigationBar:

[image]

You can change color of NavigationBar using: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setNavigationBarColor(int)

This Method won't work on API version < 21.

To change navigation bar icon colors you can use the following answers: [Change navigation bar icon color on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33104246/1105277)

Comment: What if I want to change the color of the icons?

Comment: You can use https://stackoverflow.com/q/33104246/1105277 to change navigation bar icon colors