# change navigation bar color like canva app

Tags: android

I want design splash screen like canva app. Like

[image]

(This screenshot taken from android API version 26).

I tried this code in Activity.java:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
    }
}
```

And XML code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_splash_screen">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_splash_screen">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#678ee4"
            android:textSize="28sp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33104246/8969251) recently but its not enough to change navigation bar icon color to white.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is no action bar in the screenshot.

You can create a screen without an action bar and transparent status bar and transparent navigation bar.

Create styles like below.

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.TranslucentStatus" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

Apply the above `AppTheme.NoActionBar.TranslucentStatus` to your activity in the `manifest`

The above method only works from lollipop (v21)

Comment: Its true but please see Canva App's screenshot clearly there is navigation icons with white color!

Comment: When I trying this code navigation icon color not changing.