# Android: windowLightNavigationBar not working

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

Background: My background is in web development, ruby and javascript. I'm working on a mostly react-native app, so very likely I'm missing something basic.

**What I want**

android navigation bar to be white with dark system buttons see image in link [white navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C3uy.png)

**My Current Code**

`res/values/style.xml`

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item> 
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**What is happening instead**

The background AND the buttons are white. which is not so great for UX.

** What I have Tried **

this is what got me where I am now [Change navigation bar icon color on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104246/change-navigation-bar-icon-color-on-android)

I have tried putting style.xml in a `values-v27` folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just worked on this same topic and found out you need to run at least Android 8.1 (or API level 27) on the device/emulator for this to work.

Also, I had to add this to the color of the bar:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

So, recommended steps:

- Create a values-v27 folder
- Insert the style:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
```

In your other values folder, you kind of have to live with the fact that this windowsLightNavigationBar doesn't apply...

**Small remark**

I also found a bug on this change, when putting app in background and then opening it again, the navbar buttons stay white for a second before getting the dark color

Comment: This was added in API level 27 so you can do it in your `values-v27`

Answer (score 1):

A new approach would be:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white)
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as intended for me. Make sure you have the file name and file path written correctly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpB47.jpg

Comment: hmm ok good to know. I guess there is some other configuration that is different for me. I will do more investigating.