# windowLightNavigationBar not working on Android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm trying to make Navigation Bar Light With dark Dots on it So I made style-v27.xml with windowLightNavigationBar = true :

```
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

this feature is available in Api Level 27+ AND:

- it works fine on api 27 (android 8.1) - emulator
- it works fine on api 28 (android 9) - emulator
- **it's NOT working on api 29 (android 10) - emulator**

On Android 10 dot remains White And Background is Also White!:

[image]

by the way I'm Targeting on Api 29.
I have tested on "EMULATOR". I haven't access to a real Android 10 device to confirm this bug is also there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56870080/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thank you for response! I already read that topic. it's not what I mean Or what I want. I get This Functionality on api 27 & api 28 very well. problem is api 29 (android 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an AVD bug not an android platform bug. close android Q AVD and Update android 10 SDK system files. re open AVD. problem solved.

if this not helped, Delete AVD and Recreate it.

Comment: I'm facing this problem on Pixel with Android 10 (QP1A.191005.007.A3). So it wasn't just AVD's issue.

Comment: After a few hours of debugging, I found that this is happening on the Google Pixel in combination with this line of code: window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE, all other Android versions (in emulator) works fine.

Comment: @Tomas you are my hero!  Been trying to debug this for hours and figure out what random flag is breaking this!  Disabling SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE was the fix I needed!

Answer (score 1):

If you have set System UI visibility (e.g. `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`) this should do the trick in your main activity via `onCreate()`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
}
```

Thanks [@tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3796931/tomas)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white)
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
}
```