# React Native: Android windowLightNavigationBar not change button colors

Tags: android, android-layout, react-native

In my react-native application, I want to change the bottom navigation bar color to white. I was able to change the color to white by adding the following line to my `src/main/res/value/styles.xml` file.

```
 <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

But when I run it on a simulator or in a physical device. It shows as follows. I want to have the buttons in the bottom navigation bar to be highlighted so that users can clearly see the buttons.

**Actual Output**

[image: Nav bar image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

**What I Did So far**

1. Tried adding  `<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>` to styles.xml
   file.
2. Tried by creating `values-28` folder and adding the styles.xml file
   as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56870080/7704650).
3. Tried changing `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to
   `parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar`
4. Tried creating a new simulator as mentioned
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59479346/7704650)
5. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47341768/7704650) as well.

But none of them seems to fix my issue.

My `styles.xml` files look like this.

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

`build.gradle` looks like this.

```
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    minSdkVersion    = 27
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

I've tested on the following devices

1. Pixel 4 API 30 (Simulator)
2. Pixel 3A XL API 27(Simulator)
3. Redmi Note 7 (Physical Device - Android 10)
4. Mi Note 10 Lite (Physical Device - Android 10)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line too.

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
```