# Does anyone know how to change the colors of the very bottom area of an Android phone with Xamarin XF?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's an example of what I mean

[image]

How can I change the color between grey and black depending on settings in my app.  I believe am looking for a solution that uses an Android Renderer.

Note that is **not a very good picture** as the bright white confused my camera.  There's actually the Android's back < the square home and another symbol that's showing in that white area.  My point is that it's showing very clearly even though I have set Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false" and I don't believe it was appearing before.

Comment: Did you try to set page background color?

Comment: This is outside of the XF page in the Android area.  The page color is already set.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment try to add in your Android project following line in your styles.xml located resources -> values:

under:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

add

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000000</item>
```

Please note it won't work on API version < 21

Comment: I think this is a very good start.  Do you know how to change the color of the icons also?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104246/change-navigation-bar-icon-color-on-android